# What is the best way of figuring out when someone reacts to a message (discord.js)

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I am trying to figure out if someone reacted to a message sent by the bot. I have tried
`reactions.awaitReactions()` but you must select a time and I just want to respond after they react. Is there any way of doing this? I have tried a few different ways of getting this but none have worked in way I wanted.

[image]

Answer (score -2, accepted):

The way I got this to work is by adding the below. This is the best way I could find because all other ways you must select a time and that just makes this all pointless.

```
 client.on('messageReactionAdd', async (reaction, user) => {
              console.log(user.id == message.author.id)
            if(user.bot) return 
            if(!user.id == message.author.id) return
            console.log(reaction.emoji)
            if(reaction.emoji.name == ''){
                message.reply("Good")
            
            }else if(reaction.emoji.name == ''){
                message.reply("Bad")
            }
    
        })
```

Comment: `(!user.id == message.author.id)` is almost certainly not what you want to do here. The `!` is evaluated first, meaning you're comparing `false == message.author.id` in any case where `user.id` is a truthy value, or `true == message.author.id` in any case where `user.id` is falsy. You likely want `user.id != message.author.id`, or the slightly less conventional form `!(user.id == message.author.id)`

Comment: While the approach is basic, you should add some details on how your code works.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

You can listen to reactions on old messages with `messageReactionAdd` event. [More info](https://v13.discordjs.guide/popular-topics/reactions.html#listening-for-reactions-on-old-messages)

```js
client.on('messageReactionAdd', async (reaction, user) => {

console.log(`${reaction.message.id}`); // message-id
console.log(`${reaction.message.content}`); // message-content
console.log(`${reaction.count}`); // how many reactions does this emoji have
?
});
```

or make a message yourself and listen to it. [More info](https://v13.discordjs.guide/popular-topics/reactions.html#awaiting-reactions)

```js
let message = await message.channel.send({content: 'Hello! Please react this message with  or anything !'});

await message.react('').then(() => message.react(''));

message.awaitReactions({ filter, max: 1, time: 60000, errors: ['time'] })
    .then(collected => {
        const reaction = collected.first();

        if (reaction.emoji.name === '') {
            message.reply('Thanks!');
        } else {
            message.reply('Thank you for reacting!');
        }
    })
    .catch(collected => {
        message.reply('You didn't react to me :(');
    });
```